# CoffeeScript CALL_END - what is it defined as?

Tags: syntax, coffeescript

According to the annotated source, the Coffee Script grammar delimits the arguments to a function call with `CALL_START ArgList OptComma CALL_END`, but I can't see where `CALL_END` is actually defined. What is it defined as?

Comment: Best guess (without looking at the source): Closing parenthesis, line break, or control keyword (`for`, `while`, `if`, `unless`, etc.). Operators (comparison, arithmetic, `typeof` etc.) don't count

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently `CALL_END` is inserted by `addImplicitParentheses` in [rewriter.coffee](http://coffeescript.org/documentation/docs/rewriter.html#section-11)